# Join multiple tables and sum results for each row in first table

Tags: php, sql, join

I have a problem with creating efficient sql query for shop statistics. I have three tables: categories, product_categories and orders_products.

Table **categories** - contains list of categories and structure looks like(short version):

```
id
name
```

Table **product_categories** - contains connections between  products and categories. Structure in short version:

```
id
product_id
category_id
```

Table **orders_products** - contains  all products what were  sold in shop. Structure below:

```
id
product_id
price
quantity
```

What I want to do is  display table with  category name and value of sold items for current category.

Problem occurs when i have over 2000 categories,  more than 20 items in each and  many sold items.

I tried:

1) Get all categories in one simple query

2) Foreach them(in php) and use  join for  products_catogories and orders_products

```
SELECT orders_products.id,orders_products.product_price_gross,orders_products.product_qty,orders_products.option_price,orders_products.rebate
          FROM product_categories
          LEFT JOIN orders_products
          ON product_categories.product_id = orders_products.product_id
```

3) Foreach result in php and sum values

4) Display results

5) Effects - hangs  db when is more that 50 categories in foreach.

I have no idea  how optimize query for that much data. I hope You could help me with that because I'm not so good with joins.

Kind regards
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do all thsi stuff in a single step, letting MySQL perform those calculations for you:

```
SELECT categories.name,
       SUM(order_products.price * order_products.quantity)
FROM order_products
LEFT JOIN product_categories ON product_categories.product_id = order_products.product_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON product_categories.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY categories.name,
         categories.id
```

This will only return the sum for categories, which contain at least a single purchase.
See this [example sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d03f/3/0).

---

### UPDATE

I further developed the SQL query ([new fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d03f/8/0)) to include quantity per category and add "empty" categories without sales to the reult by turning the JoOIN around:

```
SELECT categories.name,
       Ifnull(Sum(order_products.quantity), 0) AS quantity,
       Ifnull(Sum(order_products.price * order_products.quantity), 0) AS `Total Sales`
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN product_categories ON product_categories.category_id = categories.id
LEFT JOIN order_products ON product_categories.product_id = order_products.product_id
GROUP BY categories.name,
         categories.id
```

Comment: @MarekKaliszuk Glad I could help you. I also further improved the solution for you.

Comment: Well updated version works fine on fiddle but on live server it hangs. Query looks good but server can't handle it.

Comment: @MarekKaliszuk You might try to remove the `IFNULL` function - maybe MySQL has problems resolving it. Are there any other Errors fired, or is it solely slow?

Comment: Actually the is no errors. When I fire this via phpMyAdmin i see no results. I background I see a lot of queries and in time  server stop. Then I need to restart server.

Comment: ouch, this doesn't sound good... I do not see the problem at the moment. But I'll get back to it later.

Comment: I tired version without Ifnull -  the same situation. Hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try this,

```
SELECT orders_products.id,sum(orders_products.product_price_gross),sum(orders_products.product_qty),sum(orders_products.option_price),sum(orders_products.rebate)
          FROM product_categories
          LEFT JOIN orders_products
          ON product_categories.product_id = orders_products.product_id group by product_categories.category_id
```